# google app engine (GAE) ERROR: chown: cannot access '/app/public': No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, symfony, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform

Getting this error form first "gcloud deploy". Project is Laravel app. I've replaces production info with some dummy info in all logs and files.

I've red some older post with the same issue but no response. ¿Anyone having same issue?. I've tested with a new laravel 5.7 installation and getting same error. I've deleted the whole project and created a new GAE project. Don't know what else to try. Also I've tested with a Symfony 4 framework project and same problem.

```
//file: app.yaml

service: api-dev
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public
  front_controller_file: index.php
  skip_lockdown_document_root: true #<= this does the trick!!??
  #enable_stackdriver_integration: true

# Ensure we skip ".env", which is only for local development
skip_files:
- .env
- .git

env_variables:
  # Put production environment variables here.
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_ENV: local
  APP_DEBUG: true
  APP_KEY: base64:SECRET
  STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
  ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
  DB_HOST: localhost
  DB_DATABASE: api_db
  DB_USERNAME: api_user
  DB_PASSWORD: api_pwd
  DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME"

beta_settings:
  # for Cloud SQL, set this value to the Cloud SQL connection name,
  # e.g. "project:region:cloudsql-instance"
  cloud_sql_instances: "YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME"
```

My Laravel project composer.json

```
//composer.json

{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*",
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "1.8.x-dev",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.6.*",
    "vsmoraes/laravel-pdf": "^1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.3.3",
    "inacho/php-credit-card-validator": "1.*",
    "laravel/envoy": "^1.4"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
      "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\\\/cache",
      "php artisan cache:clear"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
      "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "php artisan optimize"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true
}
```

And here is the full output of the deploy command:
'gcloud app deploy deploy/dev.yaml --verbosity=debug'

```
DEBUG: No bucket specified, retrieving default bucket.
DEBUG: Using bucket [gs://staging.ibizi-dev.appspot.com].
DEBUG: Service [appengineflex.googleapis.com] is already enabled for project [ibizi-dev]
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
INFO: Need Dockerfile to be generated for runtime php
Building and pushing image for service [default]
INFO: Uploading [/var/folders/yh/t3v72_f96_9gshbgykw2yp6w0000gn/T/tmpk_BvPn/src.tgz] to [staging.ibizi-dev.appspot.com/eu.gcr.io/ibizi-dev/appengine/default.20181022t152439:latest]
DEBUG: Using runtime builder root [gs://runtime-builders/]
DEBUG: Loading runtimes manifest from [gs://runtime-builders/runtimes.yaml]
INFO: Reading [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x110774650>]
DEBUG: Resolved runtime [php] as build configuration [gs://runtime-builders/php-default-builder-20180926113101.yaml]
INFO: Using runtime builder [gs://runtime-builders/php-default-builder-20180926113101.yaml]
INFO: Reading [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x11078d150>]
Started cloud build [c874e7e6-d67b-443b-9cc0-169aa6f4dd58].
DEBUG: GCS logfile url is https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/staging.ibizi-dev.appspot.com/o/log-c874e7e6-d67b-443b-9cc0-169aa6f4dd58.txt?alt=media
To see logs in the Cloud Console: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/c874e7e6-d67b-443b-9cc0-169aa6f4dd58?project=702099999392
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 404 (no log yet; keep polling)
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 205 bytes)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- REMOTE BUILD OUTPUT -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
starting build "c874e7e6-d67b-443b-9cc0-169aa6f4dd58"

FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://staging.ibizi-dev.appspot.com/eu.gcr.io/ibizi-dev/appengine/default.20181022t152439:latest#1540214682717948
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 416 (no new content; keep polling)
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 529 bytes)
Copying gs://staging.ibizi-dev.appspot.com/eu.gcr.io/ibizi-dev/appengine/default.20181022t152439:latest#1540214682717948...
- [1 files][  798.0 B/  798.0 B]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/798.0 B.                                      
BUILD
Starting Step #0
Step #0: Pulling image: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/php/gen-dockerfile@sha256:2528f753fe7726eb4068d7020d11ecc97216b3ab9e4cb7728edda98cd61b410c
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 1446 bytes)
Step #0: sha256:2528f753fe7726eb4068d7020d11ecc97216b3ab9e4cb7728edda98cd61b410c: Pulling from gcp-runtimes/php/gen-dockerfile
Step #0: Digest: sha256:2528f753fe7726eb4068d7020d11ecc97216b3ab9e4cb7728edda98cd61b410c
Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/php/gen-dockerfile@sha256:2528f753fe7726eb4068d7020d11ecc97216b3ab9e4cb7728edda98cd61b410c
Step #0: + php /builder/create_dockerfile.php create --php72-image gcr.io/google-appengine/php72@sha256:ab499cb6f2419351ee7db259ae88721f9861935659b42007727395b80226a809 --php71-image gcr.io/google-appengine/php71@sha256:d5dbccb1e6dcc6d26c2df23c464f191ea10ef2bf8e9e18e6d13df3c6770b92a1 --php70-image gcr.io/google-appengine/php70@sha256:cf215595a9d4540762724721ab19837abb9af43645963fa0bd29cc31a2960529 --php56-image gcr.io/google-appengine/php56@sha256:0e57acbab18ce2dba8142dff708157ffdacdefbbdfa480d9068382431fd60fb5
Step #0: 
Step #0: There is no PHP runtime version specified in composer.json, or
Step #0: we don't support the version you specified. Google App Engine
Step #0: uses the latest 7.2.x version.
Step #0: We recommend pinning your PHP version by running:
Step #0: 
Step #0: composer require php 7.2.* (replace it with your desired minor version)
Step #0: 
Step #0: Using PHP version 7.2.x...
Step #0: 
Finished Step #0
Starting Step #1
Step #1: Pulling image: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:ae2ac38e0aba542add006c47eb4a5820b819f9fa74ada0673d2910387e0f1c0e
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 354 bytes)
Step #1: sha256:ae2ac38e0aba542add006c47eb4a5820b819f9fa74ada0673d2910387e0f1c0e: Pulling from cloud-builders/docker
Step #1: e5c573070776: Already exists
Step #1: a7e8e7eaedca: Already exists
Step #1: 3c2cba919283: Already exists
Step #1: 2e2f0b8e1d16: Pulling fs layer
Step #1: 2e2f0b8e1d16: Verifying Checksum
Step #1: 2e2f0b8e1d16: Download complete
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 416 (no new content; keep polling)
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 416 (no new content; keep polling)
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 416 (no new content; keep polling)
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 416 (no new content; keep polling)
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 416 (no new content; keep polling)
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 416 (no new content; keep polling)
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 416 (no new content; keep polling)
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 1636 bytes)
Step #1: 2e2f0b8e1d16: Pull complete
Step #1: Digest: sha256:ae2ac38e0aba542add006c47eb4a5820b819f9fa74ada0673d2910387e0f1c0e
Step #1: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:ae2ac38e0aba542add006c47eb4a5820b819f9fa74ada0673d2910387e0f1c0e
Step #1: Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.632kB
Step #1: Step 1/9 : FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/php72@sha256:ab499cb6f2419351ee7db259ae88721f9861935659b42007727395b80226a809
Step #1: sha256:ab499cb6f2419351ee7db259ae88721f9861935659b42007727395b80226a809: Pulling from google-appengine/php72
Step #1: Digest: sha256:ab499cb6f2419351ee7db259ae88721f9861935659b42007727395b80226a809
Step #1: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/google-appengine/php72@sha256:ab499cb6f2419351ee7db259ae88721f9861935659b42007727395b80226a809
Step #1:  ---> 66030c9a7cc4
Step #1: Step 2/9 : ENV DOCUMENT_ROOT='/app/public' ENABLE_STACKDRIVER_INTEGRATION='1' LOG_CHANNEL='stackdriver' APP_LOG='errorlog' APP_ENV='demo' APP_DEBUG='' APP_KEY='base64:+9Lz6fgTo+I5NtJgwNctYuFaaDBNdiL1OpNlhzdPiXs=' STORAGE_DIR='/tmp' DB_HOST='localhost' DB_DATABASE='pms_dev' DB_USERNAME='root' DB_PASSWORD='TMvsds666' DB_SOCKET='/cloudsql/ibizi-dev:europe-west1:pmsapi-dev' FRONT_CONTROLLER_FILE='index.php' COMPOSER_FLAGS='--no-dev --prefer-dist' DETECTED_PHP_VERSION='7.2' IS_BATCH_DAEMON_RUNNING='true'
Step #1:  ---> Running in 7594ef12b822
Step #1: Removing intermediate container 7594ef12b822
Step #1:  ---> 142b1c897658
Step #1: Step 3/9 : COPY . $APP_DIR
Step #1:  ---> f981d2d61e5d
Step #1: Step 4/9 : RUN chown -R www-data.www-data $APP_DIR
Step #1:  ---> Running in 2acb68030e93
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 363 bytes)
Step #1: Removing intermediate container 2acb68030e93
Step #1:  ---> 4725933d3fe3
Step #1: Step 5/9 : RUN /build-scripts/composer.sh
Step #1:  ---> Running in d754ce7f2927
Step #1: Removing intermediate container d754ce7f2927
Step #1:  ---> 3f19b1e63bed
Step #1: Step 6/9 : RUN /bin/bash /build-scripts/move-config-files.sh
Step #1:  ---> Running in 10b9531680b7
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 975 bytes)
Step #1: Moving user supplied config files...
Step #1: Removing intermediate container 10b9531680b7
Step #1:  ---> 45771fd2253a
Step #1: Step 7/9 : RUN /usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
Step #1:  ---> Running in 67614392383d
Step #1: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
Step #1: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
Step #1: Removing intermediate container 67614392383d
Step #1:  ---> 6d3a14951445
Step #1: Step 8/9 : RUN /bin/bash /build-scripts/lockdown.sh
Step #1:  ---> Running in 706cf97d0d6d
Step #1: chown: cannot access '/app/public': No such file or directory
Step #1: Locking down the document root...
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c /bin/bash /build-scripts/lockdown.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:ae2ac38e0aba542add006c47eb4a5820b819f9fa74ada0673d2910387e0f1c0e" failed: exit status 1
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4] complete. Result: {
    "metadata": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1.BuildOperationMetadata", 
        "build": {
            "finishTime": "2018-10-22T13:25:11.466503939Z", 
            "status": "FAILURE", 
            "timeout": "600s", 
            "startTime": "2018-10-22T13:24:45.495313971Z", 
            "artifacts": {
                "images": [
                    "eu.gcr.io/ibizi-dev/appengine/default.20181022t152439:latest"
                ]
            }, 
            "logsBucket": "staging.ibizi-dev.appspot.com", 
            "results": {
                "buildStepImages": [
                    "", 
                    ""
                ]
            }, 
            "id": "c874e7e6-d67b-443b-9cc0-169aa6f4dd58", 
            "timing": {
                "FETCHSOURCE": {
                    "endTime": "2018-10-22T13:24:51.044559960Z", 
                    "startTime": "2018-10-22T13:24:47.603211198Z"
                }, 
                "BUILD": {
                    "endTime": "2018-10-22T13:25:10.480688954Z", 
                    "startTime": "2018-10-22T13:24:51.120689972Z"
                }
            }, 
            "source": {
                "storageSource": {
                    "object": "eu.gcr.io/ibizi-dev/appengine/default.20181022t152439:latest", 
                    "bucket": "staging.ibizi-dev.appspot.com"
                }
            }, 
            "options": {
                "substitutionOption": "ALLOW_LOOSE", 
                "logging": "LEGACY"
            }, 
            "steps": [
                {
                    "status": "SUCCESS", 
                    "name": "gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/php/gen-dockerfile@sha256:2528f753fe7726eb4068d7020d11ecc97216b3ab9e4cb7728edda98cd61b410c", 
                    "args": [
                        "--php72-image", 
                        "gcr.io/google-appengine/php72@sha256:ab499cb6f2419351ee7db259ae88721f9861935659b42007727395b80226a809", 
                        "--php71-image", 
                        "gcr.io/google-appengine/php71@sha256:d5dbccb1e6dcc6d26c2df23c464f191ea10ef2bf8e9e18e6d13df3c6770b92a1", 
                        "--php70-image", 
                        "gcr.io/google-appengine/php70@sha256:cf215595a9d4540762724721ab19837abb9af43645963fa0bd29cc31a2960529", 
                        "--php56-image", 
                        "gcr.io/google-appengine/php56@sha256:0e57acbab18ce2dba8142dff708157ffdacdefbbdfa480d9068382431fd60fb5"
                    ], 
                    "env": [
                        "GAE_APPLICATION_YAML_PATH=dev.yaml"
                    ], 
                    "timing": {
                        "endTime": "2018-10-22T13:24:53.076290422Z", 
                        "startTime": "2018-10-22T13:24:51.120719923Z"
                    }, 
                    "pullTiming": {
                        "endTime": "2018-10-22T13:24:51.939222557Z", 
                        "startTime": "2018-10-22T13:24:51.120719923Z"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "status": "FAILURE", 
                    "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:ae2ac38e0aba542add006c47eb4a5820b819f9fa74ada0673d2910387e0f1c0e", 
                    "args": [
                        "build", 
                        "-t", 
                        "eu.gcr.io/ibizi-dev/appengine/default.20181022t152439:latest", 
                        "--network=cloudbuild", 
                        "."
                    ], 
                    "env": [
                        "GAE_APPLICATION_YAML_PATH=dev.yaml"
                    ], 
                    "timing": {
                        "endTime": "2018-10-22T13:25:10.374276995Z", 
                        "startTime": "2018-10-22T13:24:53.076303098Z"
                    }, 
                    "pullTiming": {
                        "endTime": "2018-10-22T13:25:06.452731685Z", 
                        "startTime": "2018-10-22T13:24:53.076303098Z"
                    }
                }
            ], 
            "sourceProvenance": {
                "resolvedStorageSource": {
                    "generation": "1540214682717948", 
                    "object": "eu.gcr.io/ibizi-dev/appengine/default.20181022t152439:latest", 
                    "bucket": "staging.ibizi-dev.appspot.com"
                }, 
                "fileHashes": {
                    "gs://staging.ibizi-dev.appspot.com/eu.gcr.io/ibizi-dev/appengine/default.20181022t152439:latest#1540214682717948": {}
                }
            }, 
            "projectId": "ibizi-dev", 
            "images": [
                "eu.gcr.io/ibizi-dev/appengine/default.20181022t152439:latest"
            ], 
            "substitutions": {
                "_GAE_APPLICATION_YAML_PATH": "dev.yaml", 
                "_OUTPUT_IMAGE": "eu.gcr.io/ibizi-dev/appengine/default.20181022t152439:latest"
            }, 
            "createTime": "2018-10-22T13:24:44.661298334Z", 
            "logUrl": "https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/c874e7e6-d67b-443b-9cc0-169aa6f4dd58?project=702099999392"
        }
    }, 
    "done": true, 
    "name": "operations/build/ibizi-dev/Yzg3NGU3ZTYtZDY3Yi00NDNiLTljYzAtMTY5YWE2ZjRkZDU4", 
    "error": {
        "message": "Build failed; check build logs for details", 
        "code": 2
    }
}
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 416 (no new content; keep polling)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cloud build failed. Check logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/c874e7e6-d67b-443b-9cc0-169aa6f4dd58?project=702099999392 Failure status: UNKNOWN: Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davidpv/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 841, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/davidpv/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 770, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/davidpv/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 90, in Run
    parallel_build=False)
  File "/Users/davidpv/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 620, in RunDeploy
    flex_image_build_option=flex_image_build_option)
  File "/Users/davidpv/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 405, in Deploy
    image, code_bucket_ref, gcr_domain, flex_image_build_option)
  File "/Users/davidpv/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 282, in _PossiblyBuildAndPush
    self.deploy_options.parallel_build)
  File "/Users/davidpv/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/deploy_command_util.py", line 449, in BuildAndPushDockerImage
    return _SubmitBuild(build, image, project, parallel_build)
  File "/Users/davidpv/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/deploy_command_util.py", line 482, in _SubmitBuild
    build, project=project)
  File "/Users/davidpv/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/cloudbuild/build.py", line 150, in ExecuteCloudBuild
    self.WaitAndStreamLogs(build_op)
  File "/Users/davidpv/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/cloudbuild/build.py", line 195, in WaitAndStreamLogs
    + message)
BuildFailedError: Cloud build failed. Check logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/c874e7e6-d67b-443b-9cc0-169aa6f4dd58?project=702099999392 Failure status: UNKNOWN: Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cloud build failed. Check logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/c874e7e6-d67b-443b-9cc0-169aa6f4dd58?project=702099999392 Failure status: UNKNOWN: Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details
```

Comment: this might not be the problem but, you may need `composer require google/cloud-debugger` and `composer require ext-stackdriver_debugger:*
`   see [here](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/php)

Comment: or just try without  `enable_stackdriver_integration: true`

Comment: That change makes no difference in the output. Still getting same error.

Comment: As the console output suggests, the actual build log that will contain the build failure is at  https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/c874e7e6-d67b-443b-9cc0-169aa6f4dd58?project=702099999392 . Can you share that with us?

Comment: Is the same that is already posted

Answer (score 2):

I just found that by adding "skip_lockdown_document_root: true" in the "runtime_config" node it does not fail anymore. Does anyone can explain for dummies what does this action? I haven't found a clear explanation. I'd like to know what's going on under the hood with this "skip_locakdown_document_root" option. I can guess that it does a chmod/chown a that's it, but I'd like to confirm this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but it happened that I've changed the way I deployed project, and the path was no longer correct.

I used the mentioned "skip_lockdown_document_root" option to be able to start the VM, ssh into it and understand the problem. (I had error 500)